# PyDic segfaults when key > size 1

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to use python bindings to interface a simple python wrapper around my c++ code. I am currently wanting to return a map of values. When I try to create a dictionary entry my application segfaults when the key > size 1. Even ignoring the returning of the object I still get the error. Only adding "ke" segfaults as well. I have successfully returned a dict with {"k": 10} but that is it.

C++:

```
extern "C" void Test() {
    signal(SIGSEGV, handler);   // install our handler
    PyObject* results = PyDict_New();
    printf("Adding k\n");
    PyDict_SetItemString(results, "k", PyLong_FromLong(3000));
    printf("Adding ke\n");
    PyDict_SetItemString(results, "ke", PyLong_FromLong(3000));
    printf("Adding key\n");
    PyDict_SetItemString(results, "key", PyLong_FromLong(3000));
}
```

Python:

```
import ctypes

_test_bench = ctypes.CDLL('<path_to_so>')


_test_bench.Test.argtypes = None
_test_bench.Test.restype = None


def test() -> None:
    global _test_bench
    _test_bench.Test()


test()
```

Output:

```
Adding k
Adding ke
Error: signal 11:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the Python API from a library loaded with `CDLL`. You need to use `PyDLL`.

(Also, don't forget to do your refcount management. That's not the cause of the crash, but it is still a problem.)

Comment: @hestia: You wouldn't need to decref the dict itself if you were returning it, because ownership of your reference would pass to the code receiving the object. However, you do need to decref the values you're setting in the dict. The dict isn't stealing your references there; you still own the references returned by `PyLong_FromLong`, and you're responsible for clearing those references. (The dict creates new references to its keys and values.)